# How to create a collage with images and labels?

Tags: floats, tabularx, includegraphics

I am trying to create  collage. Am able to create the images, but not yet with the text left and above it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CCC}
\includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
    &   \includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
        &   \includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
    \\[3ex]
\includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
    &   \includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
        &   \includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You could have a 4-column x 3-row table (instead of 3x2), and rotate the text in the first column with `\rotatebox{90}{....}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tabularray` package:

[image: tabularray]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}



\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
  \begin{tblr}
    {
      width     = {\textwidth},
      colspec   = { Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c] },
      rowsep = 1ex,
      rowspec   = { Q[m] },
%      hlines,
%      vlines,
      row{1}    = {font=\bfseries, bg=brown9, font=\sffamily},
      cell{1}{1}    = {bg=white},
      cell{2-3}{1}    = {cmd=\rotatebox[{origin=tl}]{90}},
%      cell{3}{1}    = {cmd=\rotatebox[{origin=tl}]{90}},
    }
&
echo-Doppler 
&
CT-MRA
&
CTA
\\
\parbox{1.5cm}{Healthy subject}
&
\includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
    & 
      \includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
        &   
\includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
    \\
Patient\ \ \ \ \ 
&
\includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
&
   \includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
&
   \includegraphics[width=3.0cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
        \end{tblr}
  \end{figure}




    \end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*

Lining up text and images by centering them all on the baseline with `\parbox`es, then rotating the text with `origin=c` option, gives the desired result.

[image: centering]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\iw}{2.8cm}
\newcommand{\iwp}{2.8cm}


\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
  \begin{tblr}
    {
      width     = {\textwidth},
      colspec   = { Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c] },
%      hlines,
%      vlines,
      row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, bg=brown9, font=\sffamily},
      cell{1}{1}    = {bg=white},
      cell{2-3}{1}    = {cmd=\rotatebox[{origin=c}]{90}},
    }
&
echo-Doppler 
&
CT-MRA
&
CTA
\\
\parbox{\iwp}{\centering Healthy \\subject}
&
\parbox[c]{\iwp}{\includegraphics[width=\iw]{example-image}}
& 
\parbox[c]{\iwp}{\includegraphics[width=\iw]{example-image}}
&   
\parbox[c]{\iwp}{\includegraphics[width=\iw]{example-image}}
\\
\parbox{\iwp}{\centering Patient}
&
\parbox[c]{\iwp}{\includegraphics[width=\iw]{example-image}}
&
\parbox[c]{\iwp}{\includegraphics[width=\iw]{example-image}}
&
\parbox[c]{\iwp}{\includegraphics[width=\iw]{example-image}}
\end{tblr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the "Patient" is not centered but a bit to the left. Do you have the solution to this? tried centring and origin=tc instead of origin=tl but that didnt work.

Comment: No, I don't know. You can ask a separate question. Perhaps `\adjustbox` could help.

Comment: Found a workaround - see amended answer. The images were originally sitting on the baseline; now they are centred around it, along with the text, so `origin=c` now works as intuitively expected.